# method for executing code after button onClick() is executed

Tags: android, button

Is there any method with Android for Buttons that can be run post clicking a button. For example; something along the lines of `btn.postClick()` or btn.postExecute?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ? `onClick()` is Event down and an up withing fraction of time . postClick does not make any sense .  If you want an delay in running code then use `Handler`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this You can use `Handler` for delay after click in button

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // perform your action here
                }
            }, 3000); //time in missliseconds
        }
    });
```